# XCTest cannot read launch arguments

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ui-testing

I am running a UI test and in the setUp() method I set a launch argument:

```
self.app = XCUIApplication()
self.app.launch()        
self.app.launchArguments.append("UITesting")
```

Then later in the testI try to read the launch argument this way:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("UITesting") {
    // do something
}
```

But the code inside the if is never executed. How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set launch arguments after the app is already launched.

You shall set the launch arguments and environment variables, and then launch the app

```
    app.launchArguments.append("UITesting")
    app.launch()
```

Comment: The first part is right: "You cannot set launch arguments after the app is already launched". Indeed if I set the arguments before launching the app, everything runs fine! but it's not necessary to pass environment variables, also arguments are fine. Please edit the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I’m glad the answer has helped you!